# MVC 3 Cannot exempt page from forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, webforms

In a mixed MVC3 / Web forms application, we use forms authentication.  I am trying to exempt a page from the loginUrl redirect.

In the web.config:

The forms authentication config (snippit):

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
 <system.web>  
  ...
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Authorization/Auth/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
  ...
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Below that the location element for the page to be exempted:

```
  <location path="foo.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>  
  </location>
```

I have tried both "?" and "*" in the allow users in the location element but to no avail.  When I try to hit foo.aspx, I get a redirect to the loginUrl instead.

Comment: Is Anonymous Authentication enabled in IIS?

Comment: Yes it is enabled.  And it's IIS7 btw.

Comment: Does the IIS_IUSers group have read permission for the file?

Comment: Did you see this article? http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx

Comment: justinb138 - I did give the group permissions but it did not change the behavior.